# Parameter Estimation

Tags: r, optimization, statistics

I have data sets and the sinusoidal model   y=fc+fe sin(2π(x-t0)/12) in which fc, fe and t0 are the parameters . I have to calculate the parameter estimation of fc and fe (keep t0 constant). Is there any R library that can do this?

Considering the two parameters of amplitude fc and fe simultaneously, delimit (using the χ2 variation method) the area in that parameter space that contains 95.4% confidence.

Comment: Can you provide more context on what values these data sets contain (is it `x`,`y`, and `t0`)? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Aziz , the x contain no of months, y contact fraction lost in each month and t0 is a third parameter.

Comment: Use the `nls` function in R. it is used exactly for this kind of problems

Answer (score 0):

you can replace Sin(somethings) by its D.L 
sin(x) = x - x^3/6 +x^5/120 +........
and you get a polynomial model